# Vue jest test activated lifecycle

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

So i have a problem using jest and vue-test-utils to test my component with activated life cycle, for example i have component with activated hook like this

```
activated() {
  console.log('activated')
  this.activatedData = true
}
```

it will not be triggered after i executed shallowMount

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, { localVue })
expect(wrapper.vm.activatedData).toBe(true) // failed because it still false
```

how do i test the activated life cycle then?

Answer (score 3):

activated life cycle hook triggers only on keep-alive components.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#activated

For non keep-alive components use mounted instead.

If keep-alive component, have in mind that is not called during server-side rendering. If not the case, provide additional info

Answer (score 3):

You can call the `activated()` hook this way:

```
wrapper.vm.$options.activated[0].call(wrapper.vm)
```

Looks hacky, but I haven't found any other way.

- `wrapper.vm.$options.activated` is an array, so you need to access the first element
- then you have to use `call(wrapper.vm)`, to set the context (`this` variable), so it's called on your component and it can access its methods, data, etc.

This solution is valid for `@vue/test-utils 1.1.1`. I wouldn't consider it particularly safe and reliable, because it does not use the public API, so at some point it may stop working.
It's still better than nothing though.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This answer is wrong. The root cause of the author's question issue is not using of `<keep-alive>` wrapper, as it's mentioned in Vue 2 docs. If it's used any hacks aren't required, because the `activated` hook will be called by vue-test-utils. If `<keep-alive>` is not suitable, then the `mounted` event should be used instead of the `activated`.

Comment: The question is about shallow mounting. Even if `vue-test-utils` called `activated` hook on your component within its ancestor’s `<keep-alive>` context, your component would get stubbed due to using shallow mount.

Also, what if someone wants to test deactivating and then activating their component again? 
They can’t rely just on mounting, they need a way to call the handler explicitly.

Therefore I think that the original answer actually solves the problem, so it's not wrong.