# How to test activated lifecyle in jest

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs

I have this code in my vue file:

```
activated(): void {
this.name = “”;
this.emailAddress = “”;
this.birthdate = “”;
}
```

How can I test this one in jest? That will check if the data inside activated lifecycle is empty?

I tried the solution here but it wont work for me:

[Vue jest test activated lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61903982/vue-jest-test-activated-lifecycle)

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Please, explain your case in details, this includes package versions and necessary code to reproduce it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Otherwise the answered question is applicable, the solution at least was workable at some point

Answer (score 0):

To ease testing and maintenance you can move actions inside lifecycle hooks to separate methods:

```
activated(): void {
  this.onActivated();
},
methods: {
  onActivated(): void {
    this.name = “”;
    this.emailAddress = “”;
    this.birthdate = “”;
  }
}
```

and then check the result after triggering this method in test by running:

```
wrapper.vm.onActivated();
expect(wrapper.vm.name).toBe("");
expect(wrapper.vm.emailAddress).toBe("");
expect(wrapper.vm.birthdate).toBe("");
```

Manually running `activated()` is `Vue` functionality and should **not** be including in tests.